# segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write this code, but it gives me segmentation fault after running the program, could you please help to sort it out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int salary;
    char* name;
} employee ;

int main(){
    employee p[2];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<2; i++){
            printf("enter sal ");
            scanf("%d", &p[i].salary);

           printf("enter name ");
           scanf("%s", &p[i].name);
        }
        for(i=0;i<2; i++){
           printf("p %d",p[i].salary);
           printf("p %s",p[i].name);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure field `name` is just a wild character pointer.

```
char* name;
```

you are reading the user input as:

```
scanf("%s", &p[i].name);
```

into the memory pointed by `name` which could be anywhere.

To fix this you need to dynamically allocate memory pointed to by `name` or you can change `name` to a `char` array of size one greater than the max length of the name possible.

```
char name[MAX];
```

Answer (score 5):

- You need to allocate memory for the name field: `p[i].name = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_LEN)`
- Also, the `scanf("%s", &p[i].name)` should read `scanf("%s", p[i].name)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the & operator when scanf'ing to pointer. And you need to malloc `p[i].name`

```
       scanf("%s", p[i].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating memory for char* name. change your data structure to

```
typedef struct
{ 
    int salary; 
     char name[50]; 
}
```

or allocate memory using malloc

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate memory for `p[i].name`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reserve memory for the `name` member of each instance of `employee`:

```
p[i].name = (char*)malloc(expected_max_size);
```

just before the `scanf` for that variable. Declaring a pointer to char `char*` does not assign memory for the actual string pointed to, but just for the pointer itself, and in your example it is not initialized. By using `malloc` you reserve a piece of memory and makes the pointer point to it. You have to be careful with bounds checking, because you have to reserve the memory beforehand, enough to hold what the user is writing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the "name" string in your structure. Do this using malloc() or by declaring name as an array of a given size (char name[SIZE]).